# Send commands (e.g: shutdown, restart) to device - iotagent-ul

Tags: fiware

Is it possible to send commands to a device using iotagent-ul?

I want to have the ability to manage my device remotely and perform tasks such as shutdown and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can find [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/docs/usermanual.md#commands-syntax) the syntax of the commands sent by the IoT agent for a UL device.

Those commands are sent to the device from the agent each time an "update context" operation is received at the northbound API of the agent, usually from an [Orion Context Broker](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion) instance that has registered the agent as the context provider for a context entity related to the device. I.e. at Orion you perform an "update context" operation in order to modify some attribute modeling a command (for instance, a "shutdown" attribute), and such "update context" is forwarded to the agent since it is the registered context provider for the entity/device. Then, the agent translates the "update context" operation into the specific UL protocol I've linked to you.